# GMT is showing wrong date 5 hrs. back

Tags: ios, nstimezone

I am using this code to show date which i am getting from server but with GMT it is showing time of 5 hrs. back

```
-(NSString *)getDateStringFromServer:(NSDate *)date{
  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
  [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:+0000]];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy h:mm a"];
  NSString *dateAsString = [formatter stringFromDate:date]; 
  return dateAsString;
}
```

Comment: And what are the value of `dateAsString` and `date`?

Answer (score 1):

set time zone accordingly.
as you are getting time according to gmt when you use +0000

```
[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:+0000]
```

to get time according to your timeZone set seconds difference according to your time zone.
my timezone is GMT+5
and I set +(3600*5).

```
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:+(3600*5)]];
```

and got correct output "12 Dec 2014 7:55 PM".

which previously was "12 Dec 2014 7:55 PM" with +0000 and was wrong and 5 hrs back..

updated:
as suggested by @Tom Harrington you should use local time instead of timezoneforSecondsFromGmt.

```
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
```

Comment: Using `timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT` is almost always wrong. You should use the name for your local time zone.

Comment: yes you are right instead of using seconds you can use localTimeZone.
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];